# How to fix library not found -lX11 errors while compiling Wordnet on MAC OSX?

Tags: macos, wordnet

When compiling Wordnet 3.0 on Mac OSX, I get warnings about missing libraries.

> library not found for -lX11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all static X libraries from the Makefile.

Original

> TK_LIBS = -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11 -Wl,-weak-lXss -lXext -L/usr/X11/lib -lXft -lX11 -L/usr/X11/lib -lfreetype -L/usr/X11/lib -lfontconfig -L/usr/X11/lib -lXrender -lX11  -lpthread -fra>

Changed

> TK_LIBS = -L/usr/X11/lib -Wl -L/usr/X11/lib -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation  -lz  -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation.

Need to do this in src/Makefile.